# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager allows only limited connection to the host at a time

Tags: java, httpclient, pooling

My application's requirement is to run on multithreaded environment. I am using `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` to maintain pool of 20 connections per route.

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();   

cm.setMaxTotal(200);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
```

I am getting the `HttpClient` from this connection Manager and trying to execute the get request by multiple treads.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

                for(int k =0; k <25; k++){       
                     executor.execute(getData);
                }
                executor.shutdown();
```

`getData` method is executing `HttpGet` request by using the `HttpClient`.

But the issue is, only 5-6 connection are being used at a time, instead of 20 mentioned above. So the `HttpClient` seems to blocking the connection call.
Has anyone encounter the same issue or has better solution to it.

Comment: turn on logging ( WIRE , HEADER )  and you should see all the respective threads and which domains they connecting to

Comment: @Sumanjeet did you solve the problem? can you provide solution